# Postfix TLS error message

Tags: postfix, ssl

I have a strange message in my Postfix server (on Debian 12) and **only** when receiving a message from Outlook:

> postfix/smtpd[1621610]: connect from
> mail-vi1eur02olkn2098.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.48.98]
> postfix/smtpd[1621610]: SSL_accept error from
> mail-vi1eur02olkn2098.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.48.98]: -1
> postfix/smtpd[1621610]: warning: TLS library problem:
> error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported
> protocol:../ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:1657: postfix/smtpd[1621610]:
> lost connection after STARTTLS from
> mail-vi1eur02olkn2098.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.48.98]

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Possible solution:  [Post in a FreeBSD discussion thread](https://forums.FreeBSD.org/threads/tls-library-problem-in-mail.87943/post-597847) about the same error in Postfix with Outlook connections.  Scroll through the whole thread for the context of the fix.  Found that thread in a Goo gle search for `postfix smtpd 'warning: TLS library problem'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error came from the fact that I imposed the usage of TLS 1.3 - changing that to

```
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1
```

solved my problem.